# Extracting data from collections with Entity Framework with SOAP web service

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, web-services, soap

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<Blog> GetAllBlogs()
    {
        using (Context db = new Context())
        {
            List<Blog> blogsItem = new List<Blog>();

            if (db.Blogs.Any(w => w.Status != EntityLayer.Enums.Status.Deleted))
            {
                foreach (var item in db.Blogs)
                {
                    blogsItem.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return blogsItem;
        }
    }
```

I have written a web service to access my blogs through my data access layer in a N-Tier architecture. But while returning the method list, I get an error like this:

[image: WebServiceError]

Comment: Please post your image so I don't have to worry about clicking on random links.

Comment: Can you please *translate* that error into English and post the error message **as text** in your question?